# Xubuntu Wireless Trouble via Kernel 5.15.0-47-generic - Ax200 chipset ASrock x570 mb - Totally New Rig

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, 22.04

Please help. Not sure what is going wrong.

```
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: X570 Phantom Gaming 4 WiFi ax
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: P4.30
    date: 02/23/2022
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: N/A
  Device-2: Intel I211 Gigabit Network driver: igb
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX200 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: 50:2F:9B:B0:8B:6D bt-v: 3.0
```

Update:

```
    [    6.414081] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.418787] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    6.418795] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    6.419052] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.592019] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.677317] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: retry init count 0
[    6.677337] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.761531] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: retry init count 1
[    6.761544] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.846618] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: retry init count 2
[ 2726.183303] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-66.ucode failed with error -2
[ 2726.183317] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-65.ucode failed with error -2
[ 2726.183327] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-64.ucode failed with error -2
[ 2726.184149] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[ 2726.184155] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[ 2726.184328] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 cc-a0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[ 2726.215687] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[ 2726.300399] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: retry init count 0
[ 2726.300415] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[ 2726.384650] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: retry init count 1
[ 2726.384662] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[ 2726.468647] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: retry init count 2
```

Update:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
06:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP [1022:1485]
```

Update:
The wifi has not worked since fresh install. Wiped the HD's, new partition table, everything. Just bought this rig; wiped the Win10 bs. There is only Xubuntu LTS on here now, linux kernel 5.15+. The Ax200 Intel onboard Wifi won't work whatever I try. I see so many other people have encountered the same issue. I'm surprised after so many years this problem still exists. I hope someone can help here, and I hope that yet another instance encourages a more sustainable solution finally.

Update:
I have now tried also the 5.19 current linux kernel, and no joy either there. Ideas? Solutions?

Update:
Ran one of the help forum's wireless scripts. Do you think I have to change the powersave option in config to 1 from 3? *Or maybe blacklist in that blacklist config file some of the microcodes except the one recommended by Intel of late?* Got all this info to add:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 20 Sep 2022 10:52 EDT -0400

Booted last: 20 Sep 2022 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 21
Release:    21
Codename:   vanessa

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.19.0-051900-generic #202207312230 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Jul 31 22:34:11 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

, ro, quiet, splash, initrd=boot\initrd.img-5.19.0-051900-generic

##### desktop ###########################

Xfce

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW [8086:0084]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
    Kernel driver in use: igb

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 045e:0024 Microsoft Corp. Trackball Explorer
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

iwlwifi               491520  0
iwlmei                 53248  1 iwlwifi
cfg80211             1003520  2 iwlmei,iwlwifi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mei                   139264  1 iwlmei
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp5s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.0.102/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp5s0
       valid_lft 172032sec preferred_lft 172032sec
    inet6 fe80::16a9:bb3:e01b:a6b0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp5s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.102 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        1098       1  0 10:39 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp5s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        I211 Gigabit Network Connection
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         igb
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.19.0-051900-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:                0. 4-1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp5s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:06.0/0000:05:00.0/net/enp5s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:05:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp5s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       e75784d2-162f-39bc-a0be-96264918ea14
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.102/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 172800
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        expiry = 1663857583
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.0.102
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::16a9:bb3:e01b:a6b0/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   e75784d2-162f-39bc-a0be-96264918ea14 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/1-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (755 - 928 @ 2), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp5s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-051900-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
depends:        cfg80211,iwlmei
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.19.0-051900-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:0:disable, 1-15:FW_DBG_PRESET Values, 16:enabled without preset value defined,Debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 16)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[iwlmei]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-051900-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mei/iwlmei.ko
license:        GPL
description:    The Intel(R) wireless / CSME firmware interface
depends:        mei,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlmei
vermagic:       5.19.0-051900-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-051900-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.19.0-051900-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

grep: /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/enable_ini: Operation not permitted
[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf]
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    9.875616] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: igb: enp5s0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[    9.875854] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp5s0: link becomes ready
[  647.556349] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CSR_RESET = 0x10
[  647.556352] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
[  647.556356] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x3f7f8c30
[  647.556359] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x3f7f8c30
[  647.556361] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x3f7f0430
[  647.556364] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x3f7f8c30
[  647.556366] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x3f7f8c30
[  647.556369] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x3f7f0830
[  647.556372] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x3f7f8030
[  647.556374] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x3f7f0830
[  647.556377] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x3f7f8030
[  647.556380] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x3f7f8030
[  647.556382] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x3f7f8830
[  647.556385] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x3f7f8430
[  647.556387] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x3f7f8c30
[  647.556390] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x3f7f8c30
[  647.556392] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x3f7f8430
[  647.556393] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
[  647.556396] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556399] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556401] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556404] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556406] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556409] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556411] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556414] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556416] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556419] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556421] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556424] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556426] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556429] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556431] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x044466c2
[  647.556432] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
[  647.556435] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0xe00c4c71
[  647.556437] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0xa00c4c71
[  647.556440] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0xe00c4c71
[  647.556442] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0xa00c4c71
[  647.556445] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0xb00c4c71
[  647.556447] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0xf00c4c71
[  647.556450] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0xb00c4c71
[  647.556452] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0xf00c4c71
[  647.556455] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0xb00c4c71
[  647.556457] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0xf00c4c71
[  647.556460] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0xa00c4c71
[  647.556462] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0xa00c4c71
[  647.556465] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0xe00c4c71
[  647.556468] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0xa00c4c71
[  647.556470] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0xe00c4c71
[  647.556471] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
[  647.556474] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x00000000
[  647.556697] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -110

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: What is the question? What is going wrong? Please [edit] the question and explain what is the problem. If the question is about Wi-Fi not working, then please add output of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`to the question. Also `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`. Is it a fresh install? Did the device work before? A lot information is needed to make an answerable question.

Comment: @Pilot6 I answered and filled in as requested. Can you help?

Comment: @Pilot6 How about now? I added a lot of more info. Any thought? I have tried everything I find online - running 5.19 kernel, 5.4x, still no joy.. Tried modprobe -r, modprobe, systemctl, no joy.

Comment: I tried also https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg221473.html 5.14 kernel, and still no joy, despite their saying it should work in Linux Kernel discussion board.

Comment: It is not Xubuntu, it is Linux Mint.

Comment: It's literally Xubuntu - Linux Mint XFCE is essentially full Xubuntu XFCE version. The guts and the network control process and drivers are the identical ones of Xubuntu and all Ubuntu repos. Could you please just help, rather than criticize/find problem with my posting? The situation is IDENTICAL to what everyone else keeps describing on ANY flavor - Xubuntu, Ubuntu, Endeavor, Arch, Manjaro. They're ALL encountering this same problem via the Linux Kernels and built-in iwlwifi firmware (which is the true source of the issue, although none of us laypeople have the skilled knowledge to know fix)